# Cancelling measures on both sides

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. Suppose I have $\mu(A)-\mu(B)\ge\mu(A)$ with $\mu(A)=+\infty$. Am I still allowed to cancel the $\mu(A)$'s from both sides and conclude that $\mu(B)=0$?

Comment: No, of course not....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly not. Let $A=\Bbb{R}$ and let $B$ be any subset with finite positive measure.